# SQL syntax error for creating function

Tags: sql

I tried to run the code below:

```
std.execute(" DELIMITER $$" +
                " CREATE FUNCTION findfood ( col VARCHAR , inp VARCHAR , c_length INT , i_length INT ) " +
                " RETURNS VARCHAR" +
                " BEGIN " +
                "   DECLARE i INT;" +
                "   SET i = 0;" +
                "   DECLARE co INT;" +
                "   SET co = 0;" +
                "   DECLARE out VARCHAR;" +
                "   DECLARE out_match VARCHAR;" +
                "   lp: LOOP" +
                "     IF CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'-',1) AS UNSIGNED) > CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inp,'-',1) AS UNSIGNED) THEN" +
                "        SET i = i+1;" +
                "        SET inp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(inp,'-',i - i_length);" +
                "     ELSEIF CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'-',1) AS UNSIGNED) < CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inp,'-',1) AS UNSIGNED) THEN" +
                "        SET out = CONCAT(out,'-',SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'-',1));" +
                "        SET co = co+1;" +
                "        SET col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'-',co - c_length);"+
                "     ELSE" +
                "        SET out_match = CONCAT(out_match,'-',SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'-',1));"  +
                "        SET co = co+1;" +
                "        SET col = SUBSTRING_INDEX(col,'-',co - c_length); " +
                "        SET i = i+1;" +
                "        SET inp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(inp,'-',i - i_length);" +
                "    END IF;" +
                "    IF i = i_length THEN" +
                "         IF co = c_length THEN" +
                "               LEAVE lp;" +
                "         ELSE" +
                "               SET out = CONCAT(out,col);" +
                "               LEAVE lp;" +
                "         END IF;" +
                "     ELSE " +
                "          IF co = c_length THEN" +
                "               LEAVE lp;" +
                "          ELSE" +
                "               ITERATE lp;" +
                "               END IF;" +
                "      END IF;" +
                "   END LOOP lp;" +
                "   SET out = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(out_match,'-',1),'_',SUBSTRING_INDEX(out,'-',1));" +
                "   RETURN out;" +
                "END $$" +
                "DELIMITER ;");
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

But I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn:115) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION findfood ( col TEXT , inp TEXT , c_length INT , i_l' at line 1

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Comment: Please format your wall of code so we can read it, and *ask an actual question*...

Comment: Print de hole sql string instead of executing it. Also, what is `DELIMITER $$`?